# Add specfic dynamic list in jsp page on runtime in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-aui

I am trying to add dynamic list on jsp page on runtime in liferay using following tag liferay-portlet: runtime :

```
< liferay-portlet: runtime portletName="169" queryString="" />
```

But it is showing nothing.

`< liferay-portlet: runtime portletName="25" queryString="" />` is working  fine.

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay Portlet(169), Dynamic Data List Display is instanceable portlet(each instanceable portlet will have postfix id with it) thats the reason 
`<liferay-portlet: runtime portletName="169" queryString="" />`
 is not working.

You have to use below snippet to add portlet(169)

`<liferay-portlet:runtime portletName="169_INSTANCE_2JmnDA0ZV2dl" queryString="" />`

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. It  is working fine. Can you please tell how i can show a dynamic list selected? Should I have to pass some name or parameter in querystring for this??